# JPA with Play Framework query for null values not working

Tags: java, playframework, jpa-2.0

Can somebody explain me why this is working:

```
Dependency d = new Dependency();
d.name = "test";
d.release = "";
d.version = "";
d.save();
Dependency D = Dependency.find("byNameAndVersionAndRelease", "test", "", "").first();
assertNotNull(D);
```

And this one not:

```
Dependency d = new Dependency();
d.name = "test";
d.release = null;
d.version = null;
d.save();
Dependency D = Dependency.find("byNameAndVersionAndRelease", "test", null, null).first();
assertNotNull(D);
```

Is it not possible to query for `null` values?

BR, Rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not that way. It does not work, because your attempt boils down to *Version=null..*, but you need *version is null*. You have to go for something like this:

```
Dependency D = Dependency.find(
"name = ? and version is null and release is null", "test").first();
```

Other possibility is to write whole JP QL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why JPA can't simply take care of this. I share your frustration!

For what it's worth, I've found the following solution works. Wherever your parameter may be null (and you want the query to return records that have null in that column), use this syntax:

```
String name = "test";
String version = null;
String release = null;
Dependency D = Dependency
    .find("name = :name "
        + "and (version = :version or (version is null and :version is null)) "
        + "and (release = :release or (release is null and :release is null)) ")
    .setParameter("name", name)
    .setParameter("version", version)
    .setParameter("release", release)
    .first();
```

Obviously, this is quite a bit more verbose, but it is quite readable and indicates clearly that you expect the parameter might sometimes be null.